# Recreating Underscore Unique function

Tags: underscore.js, unique, uniq

I'm getting an error for the test "should return all unique values contained in an unsorted array"

```
_.uniq = function(array) {
    return _.filter(array, function(item, pos){
      return _.indexOf(array, item) === pos; 
    });
};
```

Test:

```
describe('uniq', function() {
  it('should return all unique values contained in an unsorted array', function() {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4];

    expect(_.uniq(numbers)).to.eql([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
});
```

When I run the method it does return the array [1, 2, 3, 4]. But I don't know why it's not checking out.

Comment: @torazaburo is there an article you can point me to?

Comment: What is the error being reported by the assertion library in its entirety?

Comment: just that it doesn't "return all unique values contained in an unsorted array"

Comment: The error message should include something along the lines of `Expected: [1,2,3,4]. Got: SOMETHING`.

Comment: TypeError: visibleKeys.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Well, then something funny is going on, because where is `visibleKeys` coming from? You might want to open up devtools and run these tests in the browser if you can, turning on the "Stop on exceptions" flag if you need to, to catch it *in flagrante delicto*.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot, thanks!